# How to run a staging environment for App Engine Cloud Endpoints?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, maven, google-cloud-endpoints

I have 2 app engine projects that I have created in the [Developers Console](https://console.developers.google.com/project). One project is my production application and the other I plan to use for staging. I am developing my application using Cloud Endpoints.

I would like to have the applicationId, WEB_CLIENT_ID, ANDROID_CLIENT_ID, etc.. all be configurable such that in the terminal I can specify a 'stage' and 'prod' flag to use different configurations and push to to each respective project.

Something like:

`mvn appengine:update -env=production`

and

`mvn appengine:update -env=stage`

To do this I figure I'll need to parameterize `<application>` inside `appengine-web.xml` and also have the `Constants.java` file read from a config file.

How can I have different configurations for each environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A different approach that you could use would be to put all your CLIENT_IDs into the @API, @APIMethod annotations. This would allow the same code to be accessed from different clients via the authentication mechanisms.

Comment: Is there a security risk with this solution? For example, if in my web application Client ID I have the javascript origin set to localhost:8080 couldn't anyone gain access to my API?

Comment: The Client Ids are to ensure that the authorized client apps are accessing your service. On top of that, you need to put in the Authentication via the User object to ensure that a valid authentication took place and your authorization rules to allow the user or not ?

Comment: I see. Your solution is much simpler than what I was originally thinking. Although if an isolated staging environment is needed its still not clear to me what a good solution is. Ill mark your answer as correct for now.